# Installing Windows after Ubuntu on a different disk, keeping GRUB bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, boot-repair

I've got Kubuntu on the SSD currently. I'd like to have a Win10 install on the HDD.

I know Windows overrides the bootloader with its own. 
I know you can fix it by booting from a live USB and executing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

However, I am not sure where the bootloader will be placed, I'd like to ensure it's on the SSD, where Ubuntu is. How do I do so?

Comment: use `grub-install` yourself and you can specify the device to install it on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @guiverc It does. Please mark it as duplicate.

Comment: If you are using  an UEFI system there is a possibility that grub won't be replaced by Windows(done once by me).  Might need grub-update after to add windows.